# What really 'STATISTICS' do?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

What really `STATISTICS` do? and **where** to use in query optimization which senarios?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do **not** manually use statistics.  SQL Server's query optimizer does.  It is used to determine if and which indexes will help a query.

At this point, I recommend you start with reading some basics:

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966419.aspx

Answer (score 0):

one example i use:
after creating an index on the table i do

```
dbcc dbreindex(table)
update statistics table
```

after that the optimizer might actually start using the index.

Comment: `update statistics` is a one time query ? or what the benefit of repeating ?

Comment: as it says here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187348.aspx - it is.
I just use it after adding an index. Without it, queries won't always use the index i created without up-to-date statistics.

Comment: 1. You'd use ALTER INDEX. 2. ALTER INDEX will update index stats 3. You only need to update column stats http://serverfault.com/questions/228122/rebuild-index-update-statistics